# Drupal webform billing fails: State/Province field is required

Tags: webform-civicrm, payment, location

On Membership payment, using Drupal Webform, someone living in Singapore (for example) can not pay, as State/Province is required and Singapore has no State/Province defined. Gibraltar has the same.

This seems to be new. 
Do others have the same problem ? 
Is there a way around it ?

NB. State/province, where applicable, should indeed be required for Credit Card transactions. Just not for Singapore, Gibraltar, etc.

EDIT at the request of @Karing-semper-it , some screenshots

There is no difference in the gui before submitting:

[image]
[image]

However, after submitting, webform complains about a missing state/province, and civicrm does not

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try installing https://github.com/WeMoveEU/nobillingfields extension which aims at making address fields as not-required

Comment: The billing fields get pulled onto the webform as-is from CiviCRM. CiviCRM makes them required - as some payment processors based on people’s merchant account settings run address verifications to limit fraudulent transactions. A quick workaround perhaps -> create a dummy province ‘Signapore’ in CiviCRM for Signapore; use some jquery to set the field to that dummy province? You’ll see double but it should pass the form validation.

Comment: @KarinG-SemperIT thanks for the suggestion but I would have to do that for all countries without provinces. I'm pretty sure this problem is new. CiviCRM requires these fields but on their 'own' payment forms, allthough being marked as required, they are not required for countries that have no state/provinces. Ti seems webform-civicrm does not do such a check nowadays.

Comment: I know - it not a great solution - just wanted to see if that would be a quick/interim solution for you. If you attached two images to your question: a screen shot of native CiviCRM Contribution that the Webform links to and a screenshot of the Drupal Webform CiviCRM page - then I'll give it some thought.

Comment: @KarinG-SemperIT thanks for your response. Added the screenshots here. As  said, it's not just singapore.

Comment: also added an issue here https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm/issues/3036072

Answer (score 4):

[Singapore does not have States/Provinces](https://www.drupal.org/project/location/issues/636464) but there are [Regions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regions_of_Singapore#List_of_regions). But these have not made the list. You can add the regions to the civicrm_state_province table via the API Explorer

In Civi go to Support > Developer > API Explorer

In Entity select StateProvince 
In Action select Create
For Parameters:
     State = Central Region
     State Abbreviation = CR
     Country = Singapore

Scroll down and you will see an Execute button. Click that and confirm Write to Database

You can repeat this for each Region or you can do as Karin suggested and just create one state "Singapore"

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I added a province called singapore in the country singapore like this and like @karing-semper-it suggested. But that only helps singapore and not all these other countries. Also, I think we shouldn't start polluting our databases because the software just broke ...

Comment: I used this for solving an issue with Saint Lucia not having its "quarters" or "subdivisions" available in CiviCRM, throwing an error on webform submissions. 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:LC

Answer (score 1):

I did this for Joomla. I added the district information in SQL Provincial Information for Turkey. But the county information is still not selected when the province.

[enter link description here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/28546/city-town-selection-problem)