# City / Town Selection Problem

Tags: joomla, activities

I am using the City / Town option. However, county information is not available when I choose any province. When using information from provincial cities in Turkey availiable. No county. Is it a problem? How to add zone information.

[image]

Comment: City/Town isn't a built-in CiviCRM option.  Is this a custom field?

Comment: Hi Jon. City / Town is a built-in CRM option. This option is also called Country in non-Turkish CRM.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check if there is any data in the civicrm_county table? It might be that you just have to add some records in there because it is not prepopulated.

Comment: Hi, Erik.

Alameda, Contra Costa, Marin, San Francisco, San Mateo and Santa Clara. But that's not what I want.

Comment: There is a city named Erzincan in Turkey. There are districts such as Merkez, Çayırlı, İlç, Kemaliye and Refahiye connected to this city. I can choose Erzincan. But when I choose Erzincan, there is no district information. I should be able to come here and choose from here.

Comment: I understand, but is the data there in the tables? Or do you need to add those yourself? That was my question :-)

Comment: No data in the table. I can add districts myself. Let's solve this problem with private data.

Comment: Hi Erik, all the information of the county with the civicrm_county table added along with the province codes. I didn't get results.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the state/province field?

Administer>Localiztion>Address Settings

Scroll down and enable state/province instead of county

I've just checked the drupal demo(but these are standard civi settings) and after selecting Turkey as a country a range of options appear in state, nothing in county.

Cheers

Craig

Comment: I've done this before. City information available, but no county information.

Comment: The options in the state/ province table are editable (although you might have to do this from cpanel- can't remember exactly how I did it.

The options are linked to the country code. so selecting the country means the relevant state options then appear

Country>State> County follow the us model
US>California>Sacramento

So you might have to amend the state options to  what you need then turn off the county option

Comment: I added the zone information to SQL, as Erik wanted. I made the settings you defined. I have to make a choice to enter the district information, but in the case of text, the form can be entered manually. Apparently this problem will remain that way. :(

Comment: This is a problem I do not recognize on any other reports on either SE or the issue board. I think it is something specific in your installation but impossible to judge from a distance.